# How to remove corrupted windows install on hard drive?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

My computer has two hard drives (a smaller SSD and a much larger HDD). My computer was originally running Windows 10, until one day it just refused to boot. After that, I tried to just say screw it, and make the full switch over to Ubuntu.

The only problem is: I was only able to install Ubuntu on the SSD. Ubuntu can detect and recognize the HHD, but I can't reformat it, erase it or anything. Right now, my OS and all my other files are located on the SSD.

Is there any way for me to forcefully remove windows the HDD so I can finally use it again?

Comment: How do you try `reformat it` ? What steps do you take?

Comment: "Ubuntu can detect and recognize the HHD, but I can't reformat it, erase it or anything" why not? The 1st  2 would imply the latter 2 should be possible. What error do you get when manually mounting the partition from inside Ubuntu?

Comment: When I use Disks to try to reformat/clear the HHD, it tells me I cannot, because the drive is still in use.